# How to pass all variables from main funtion into a function which is defined in another script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a main script "*main.py*" where I have defined some variables and also calculated others. Towards the end of this script I want to use a function ( *helpfunc* ) which uses many of the variables defined so far in the main script and which is defined in another script, "*helpscript.py*"

main.py looks as following:

```
import pandas as pd
       "
       "
       "
from helpscript import*

a = 5
b = 3
c = 9
  "
  "
  "
y = 156
var1 = b+c+u
var2 = var1*(a+b+c...+k)
result = helpfunc(a, b, c, ..., var1, var2)
print(result)
```

helpscript.py looks as follows:

```
define helpfunc(a, b, c,..., var1, var2):
                "
                "
                "
 return result
```

I would like to avoid giving all the defined and calculated variables as in-parameters to the function. Is there any more proper way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `helpfunc` is taking many many parameters, so many that you don't want to pass them in, that indicates it may be doing too much, or that the code structure itself is off.

More broadly though, a couple of ways to pass variables around that are quicker to write... You could define a class that stores all your data.

```
class MyData:
    def __init__():
        pass

my_data = MyData()
```

And then throughout your `main.py`, as you calculate your variables you can do:

```
my_data.var_1 = var_1
my_data.var_2 = var_2
```

Then just pass the class into the `helpfunc` as the only argument.

Also, if you really do just want to pass all the variables as you have been, but just with shorthand syntax, you can use the unpacking operator.

```
my_vars = [var_1, var_2, var_3]
helpfunc(*my_vars).
```

This unpacks the elements of `my_vars` one by one in order as arguments to `helpfunc`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I am defining my helpfunction, how can I refer to specific variables in the list-variable? In other words, how do I define my helpfunction when the only variable that I want to is a list of variables?

Comment: So you define them in the function definition. For example, `def helpfunc(my_var_1, my_var_2, my_var_3, my_var_4): ...`. Now, you can call this function like `my_output = helpfunc(1, 2, 3, 4)`, or you can do `my_output = helpfunc(my_var_1=1, my_var_2=2, ...)`. Regardless of how you pass arguments when you call the function, in the function context those names always exist. In the function's code, just use `my_var_1`, etc.

In my answer's list unpacking example, that's functionally equivalent to calling `helpfunc(1, 2, 3, 4).`

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is to store all of the variables in a dictionary

```
myVars = {'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 9, ... etc}
```

and then call the function with the dictionary as an argument.

Another option is to define a class in another file which has all of those variables as properties, and then include the helper function as a class function.

Though, if your helper function relies on so much of what's in the main file, then this might indicate that the way you're breaking up your code should be changed instead. If there is a way to have the helper function in the main file, and break out pieces that only need at most a few variables in the function into other files, then that would be best.